# How can I see the thermal data of my CPU?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note-8

I have a Samsung Galaxy Note 8 with Exynos 9 CPU and use the app CPU-Z. I can see all data, but if I want to see the thermal data, there it is: "no thermal data"

Why is this? Is it because I haven't rooted my phone or is there an other reason? How can I fix this?

Comment: Thermal zones are accessible without root. Try some other app like Device Info HW. Or directly from Termux: `cat /sys/devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone*/{type,temp}`

Comment: Is your device a one with Exynos CPU? Samsung usually ships these devices in two versions with totally different CPU.

Comment: Yes, its one with an exynos chip

Comment: Aida 64, it has thermal section in it.